# how to use a modal with link_to in ruby on rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to `link_to` a button action

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newTag">
          <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New Tag
        </button>
```

i want to pass it as a `path:` to this code:

```
<%= render "shared/empty_view", path: contacts_path, title: "You do not have any tags!", action:"Create Tag", image: "/no_products.png" %>
```

I have tried following similar answers for similar questions, but i cant seem to get the right syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<%= link_to "#newTag", data: { toggle: "modal" } do %>
  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New Tag
<% end %>

<div id="newTag" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```